# Is there any option for ignoring outliers in mgcv package?

Tags: r, spline, outliers, mgcv

I am using p-splines with the mgcv package. After fitted, most of the fitted items seems good but some of them are really bad. It can be seen that the outliers affect the curve a lot. So is there any option in the mgcv package to deal with these outliers?

[FIGURE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS7L0.jpg)

[FIGURE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhUEU.jpg)

[DATA OVERVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va1Ja.jpg)

```
  library(mgcv)
  mgcv.ps <- gam(y~s(x, bs='ps'), method = "GCV.Cp")
  t.g <- predict(mgcv.ps)
```

Comment: Have you given us your data for reproducibility? Also, why not pre-process the data before fitting GAM?

Comment: If the data are bounded at 0, it probably doesn’t make sense to model them as conditionally distributed Gaussian. If you tell us more about the data, perhaps we can offer specific help.

Comment: @GavinSimpson The data sample contains more than 9800 items in it. Most of the data is good, these badly fitted models were found out by the NRMSE(rmse/mean or rmse/sd).  Say there are 55 points in one item, and there are totally 9800 different items. It's a 1-D data sample. I upload a quick look of the data.

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Due to the difference between different items is really big. I think it can't be simply defined, as the standard to pre-process the outliers.

Comment: @Zywo0 That's not the point; if your data are bounded at zero then the model you are fitting is wrong. Those points may not be outliers or have such strong influence (although i suspect they will still have influence) if you fit the right model. If the data are bounded at 0 (you can't have negatives) then you need to i) explain what the response is, ii) choose a more appropriate model/distribution and refit, then assess the lack of fit.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks so much for your reply. Due to the data sample is the frequency of the word appears per month. We can say most of the words appear more than 0 per month in the data sample. Only a few of them looks like this, So for most of the items, using the p-splines to do the curve fitting I think the model I used should be fine. But as you know, always there are some words are not so popular, so they are bounded at 0. Also due to the massive words in the data sample, I think it is difficult to figure them out before fitting model. Cause for most of the items, it fits really well.

Comment: On my point of view, when I saw these bad fitting, I think what I could do is delete the items whose mean are really small before fitting. I need to find out the most emergency top 25 in these words. But I still wanna have a look in ignoring outliers. Say if we have a single item is stable at 25, like 25 24 25 24 26 and them at a sudden it has 90 then still become 24 25 26 25, I think if ignoring the outlies could help to deal with this kind of items.

Comment: No, your model is wrong where the mean word count is low. If you have large word counts then a Gaussian approximation may work well, but the conditional distribution of the response is unlikely to be well approximated by a Gaussian when you have low expected counts as you must if most observations in this *particular set* are zero. You should look at models for count data; the obvious is the Poisson, but that won't be flexible enough to handle this kind of data as it is likely overdispersed. You could look at zero-inflated Poisson or negative binomial models or hurdle models.

Comment: In a hurdle model you have two parts; i) you model the probability that the word is present (0/1), then ii) conditional upon the word being present, you model the count of that word. model for i) is a binomial model, where as a count model is used for the model in ii). You can't just decide to remove data when you haven't fitted an appropriate model in the first place. If all this doesn't mean anything to you, read about generalised linear model, and non-Gaussian distributions for the conditional distribution of the response.